# What is causing ogr2ogr to fail to merge shapefiles without a reprojection?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, ogr, ogr2ogr, reprojection-mathematics

**Update 23-04-2018**

The main issue has been solved, I (incorrectly) assumed all the files would share the same crs. This isn't the case and zones UTM 13N to 16N are used. So with no target crs for ogr2ogr to reproject to the layers which don't have the same projection as the first one to be written get drawn with the wrong projection. Since the parameter that varies between those UTM projections in the central meridian the features are shifted east or west. This can be seen when looking at Baja California for example.

The sight mis-registration described in the question only seems to affect Baja California Sur, and is present in the source data. This suggests it is something to do with how that data has been prepared. I'll leave the question open to see if anyone can crack that...

**Original Question**

I have two simple shell [scripts](https://gist.github.com/GeoWill/880e0ee973f6e3b4faad96b72eed43d9) to download and merge some shapefiles from the Mexican electoral boundary commission. One version of the script includes `-t_srs ESPG:4326` flag and on version doesn't dictate any re-projection.

The version which doesn't re-project overlays the districts of Mexico: 
[image: Mexican states jumbled]

The version with the `t_srs` flag is almost correct:
[image: Mexican States wgs84]

But on closer inspection there are the sort of issues I would associate with projection problems as can be seen on comparison with OSM:
[image]

I would like help understanding why the version which doesn't re-project basically fails, and what the slight error in the second version is caused by.

I feel like the answer is probably in [here](http://www.gdal.org/wktproblems.html) but I haven't been able to figure it out! 
I also wondered if there's another bug that might be causing this, or if I'm mis-using ogr2ogr in some way.

The source CRS is defined in the `.prj` file as follows:

`PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_13N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-105],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]`

Comment: Can you post the native extent of the first layer? How much of Mexico is it supposed to represent? The second problem (slightly offset data) could be a GCS/datum issue, but is more likely a different accuracy issue/data source issue because the offsets are different.

Comment: If I just open it up in QGIS I get the following bounding box info: 
`CRS
EPSG:32613 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 13N - Projected
Extent
-139324.7349669880059082,1606823.7470871799159795 : 1072365.5245019600261003,3622781.3430722900666296`

Comment: In answer to your second question it's meant to represent all of Mexico